# css cursor issue

Tags: html, css

Please refer this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/EVRGr/

Here I have changed the file field to text link. While clicking this 'upload file' we can choose the system files. Now i want to change the cursor to hand while hover the 'upload file' link.

Comment: Thought something like: a:hover {cursor:hand}

Comment: @Darkshadw: It's `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: @Darkshadw There is no such thing as `cursor:hand`

Comment: But the file field action is not working.

Comment: @designersvsoft: If the issue in the question is solved, mark it as such and ask a new question :) You'll get more attention in the right areas if you ask a new question with new tags related to the file upalod not working.

Answer (score 1):

Styling the file inputs is difficult. Your CSS is hacky. Even if you somehow make it work, be aware that it might stop working overnight, as soon as the browser you view it in receives an update. If you really must have a text button instead of the standard input field, you're far better off using solutions such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `position: relative;` and `top: -40px;` on the input is covering the anchor.

Also for the pointer cursor to be displayed on anchors, you need to include the href attribute of the tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/EVRGr/1/

`cursor: pointer;` is the correct CSS and `!important` is *not* a good idea.

Comment: The hand symbol is fine. But the file field action is not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that the `cursor:pointer` is not working (By default your link/input would have this style anyway).

I can see you are trying to make it appear as if the link is the file upload control, and have put some hacky CSS in place to achieve this.

I think you will struggle to get this working cross-browser.

If you wish to style the `input[type=file]`, you can read this article for more information:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html